# Can't Upload files PHP greater than 80kb

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

i write simple php up loader, i can only able to upload files less than 100kb,

my php upload limit is 64mb, 
folder permissions are okey(i tried to implement uloadyfy it also gives the same results)

path to php info
http://ezwebdesigns.co.uk/onlinetv/info.php

path to live site
http://ezwebdesigns.co.uk/onlinetv/index.html

php code

```
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

html code

```
<form id="file_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
<input name="file" id="file" size="27" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload" /><br />
</form>
```

please help me

Comment: I try to upload a file and it seems that my file successfully uploaded on your server. Can you please write your error also?

Comment: when i upload 250kb + files browser shows always connecting..

Comment: I suggest you to contact your host/server manager. I think this problem not related to Apache or PHP configuration.

Comment: i uploaded this to anther server but same there
http://webxtreams.net/freelancer/tvstreaming/admin.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem in a Wordpress project.
The server was managed by IPS Config and the PHP is setting with Fast-CGI.
I changed this config to mod_php and this solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check out:

- [PHP Increase Upload File Size Limit](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/)

You need to set desired value for these too (see above tutorial):

- upload_max_filesize
- memory_limit
- post_max_size

*Make sure your hosting provider allows more size or talk to them just in case.*

Comment: all are enough for upload 250kb file, whats wrong with this script, i previously large files using joomla on this server :(

current limit

post_max_size 8M
memory_limit 32M
upload_max_filesize 16M

Comment: @SunethKalhara: I can see file name in but there is jQuery error on your page after upload, see via console.

Comment: ya i gave alert message when unsucessful upload. this can upload 30kb file without any trouble, but when i try to upload 250kb + files it gives error message, this also happened with above core file uploader, :(

Comment: @SunethKalhara: Then there might be some other problem, you will have to analyze closely step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your Apache settings:

```
ini_set( "upload_max_filesize","8M");
```

Comment: That's alone isn't enough to handle large files, see my answer.

Comment: current max size is upload_max_filesize 16M 
http://ezwebdesigns.co.uk/onlinetv/info.php

Comment: i used uplodfy it also gives io error when upload 250kb files
http://ezwebdesigns.co.uk/onlinetv/admin.php

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are (probably) correct but know one has mentioned php.ini is the name of the config file. If you're working locally, or have control of the server, you can edit this file without any issues.

Location varies from Os to Os but on Linux it's /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.

Adding to Sarfraz list of: `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit`, and `post_max_size` you might also want to change `max_execution_time` to prevent time out errors.

Comment: ya i added both, i checked another pc upload working fine.. my pc is 64bt windows 7 i5 pc, uploadyfy always says i/o error when i try to upload files :( still  can't find the error